# How to plot two series in one single plot with different y-axis in plot.xts in R (current version of xts)

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to recreate this plot that I made with the old (pre 0.10-0) version of xts.  Here's some example data:

```
library(xts)  # Run using xts_0.9-7

set.seed(190)
modelo_1 <- arima.sim(n = 252*8,list(ar = c(.99999),sd = sqrt(0.5)))
set.seed(256)
modelo_2 <- arima.sim(n = 252*8,list(ar = c(.9999),sd = sqrt(0.75)))

d1 <- as.Date("2008-01-01")
series_1 <- xts(modelo_1, seq(d1, by = "days", along.with = modelo_1))
series_2 <- xts(modelo_2, seq(d1, by = "days", along.with = modelo_2))
```

The code below uses the old version to create the graph I want.

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4))
plot(series_1, las = 1, main = "", mar = c(5, 2, 2, 5))
par(new = TRUE)
plot(series_2, col = 2, axes = FALSE, main = "Two Series")
axis(4, las = 1)
lnames <- c("Series 1 (left)", "Series 2 (right)")
legend("top", legend = lnames, lty = 1, cex = 0.85, col = c(1, 2), bty = "n")
```

[image]

How can I create this plot with the new version of `plot.xts()`?  Here's what I've tried, but both series use the same axis.

```
plot(cbind(series_1, series_2))
lnames <- c("Series 1", "Series 2")
addLegend("bottom", legend.names = lnames, ncol = 2, lty = 1, lwd = 1, cex = 1)
```

The old way of doing this is not working anymore, because of [this issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/196).

```
plot(series_1, las = 1, yaxis.right = FALSE,yaxis.same = FALSE)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(series_2, col = 2, bty = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(4, las = 1)
lnames <- c("Series 1", "Series 2")
legend("topleft", legend = lnames, col = 1:2, lty = 1, cex = 0.85)
```

Comment: The old way it not working anymore...

Comment: You need to add some text to your question, so it's a question.  Right now it's a bunch of code with no question at all.

Comment: thanks a lot! you´re right, I am looking for a way to plot two different series in a single plot with different y-axis, with the plot.xts (in the late version of xts).

Comment: Please edit your question to state this.

Comment: thank you! I'll do exactly like that in the next time!

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak English very well so forgive me.
Below is the code with the change so that it plots as it was before.
note that the only change was to put the index as x in the plot function. Same index for both plot() functions

```
library(xts)  # Run using xts_0.9-7

set.seed(190)
modelo_1 <- arima.sim(n = 252*8,list(ar = c(.99999),sd = sqrt(0.5)))
set.seed(256)
modelo_2 <- arima.sim(n = 252*8,list(ar = c(.9999),sd = sqrt(0.75)))

d1 <- as.Date("2008-01-01")
series_1 <- xts(modelo_1, seq(d1, by = "days", along.with = modelo_1))
series_2 <- xts(modelo_2, seq(d1, by = "days", along.with = modelo_2))
#O código abaixo usa a versão antiga para criar o gráfico que eu quero.

 plot.new()
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4))
plot(index(series_1),series_1, las = 1, main = "", 
     type = 'l', mar = c(5, 2, 2, 5))
par(new = TRUE)
plot(index(series_1),series_2, col = 2, axes = FALSE,
     type = 'l', main = "Two Series")
axis(4, las = 1)
lnames <- c("Series 1 (left)", "Series 2 (right)")
legend("top", legend = lnames, lty = 1, cex = 0.85, col = c(1, 2), bty = "n")
```